# A JavaFX GUI is working perfectly fine with Netbeans IDE, but not with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I made an Application with JavaFX and Scenebuilder in Netbeans and ist working perfectly fine, but as I try to run it with eclipse it won't work and only throws errors.

I have java 8, eclipse 2019-09 R (4.13.0), and Scenebuilder for Java 8.
Also, I have the e(fx)clipse addon for eclipse.

I can't understand why an IDE can make the difference, it is exactly the same code and Java

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/Users/User1/eclipse-workspace/guitestFX/src/application/FXMLStart.fxml:10

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at application.Main.start(Main.java:29)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FXMLStartController
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
        ... 22 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Comment: What happens if you run it from the command line instead of the IDE?

Comment: @DavidConrad there is no problem compiling it, but when i try to run it it says: Error Main Class could not be found.

Comment: What is the command you use to run it?

Comment: Thanks already figured it out. After compiling it shows me these error messages(in the main question). Again witch Netbeans it works just fine!

Comment: The name of the controller class seems to be wrong... Assuming did not place the controller class in the default package. Use the fully qualified class name in the `fx:controller` attribute...

Comment: Wow despite all files were always in the same package, java couldn't find the Controller classes, but for example, for images, there is no need for the fully qualified name, it works with just the file name. @fabian Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: FYI you can write up and accept an answer for your own questions. You might help others with a similar problem searching for a solution later on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment @fabian:

The name of the controller class seems to be wrong... Assuming did not place the controller class in the default package. Use the fully qualified class name in the fx:controller attribute...